# Как сделать чтобы каждый раз генерировалось новое число?

Tags: python

```
ran_end = str(random.randint(10000, 99999))
```

ran_end генерирует одно число. Я хочу чтобы оно генерировало каждый раз при обращение новое число

Comment: `ran_end` - переменная и она ничего не генерирует. Вызывайте каждый раз `random.randint(10000, 99999)` для того, чтобы сгенерировать новое случайное число

Comment: у меня в функциях должно быть одно и тоже число

Comment: 1) `Я хочу чтобы оно генерировало каждый раз при обращение новое число` 2) `у меня в функциях должно быть одно и тоже число` - попробуйте определиться с пожеланиями )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

сделайте переменную `ran_end` функцией, при обращении к которой, она будет возвращать новое случайное число в этом диапозоне:

```py
def ran_end():
    return str(random.randint(10000, 99999))

r_e = ran_end() # случауное число
r_e2 = ran_end() # новое случайное число
print(r_e == r_e2) # в большинстве случаев будет выдавать False
```

Comment: `ran_end = random.randint(10000, 99999).__str__`